# Include dygraphs for R in Jupyter

Tags: r, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, dygraphs

I have an R notebook that I am trying to make into a Jupyter notebook using IRkernel, which I downloaded via Anaconda.

Everything works fine except when I try to use dygraphs, which just won't display the graph.

The only thing close to an answer I could find online is: https://doc.dataiku.com/dss/latest/R/dygraphs.html but I am not able to download the dataiku library for some reason.

I tried using `conda install -c r r-dygraphs` but it has made no difference.

On the dygraphs website they don't mention anything about using it in a Jupyter notebook so I'm not sure what to do. If it isn't supported on Jupyter, can someone point me to a close alternative to dygraphs that will work on Jupyter? The time series visualisation is really great on it which is why I want to implement it in my Jupyter notebook.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If your error is something like:

```
ERROR while rich displaying an object: Error in file(file, "rb"): invalid 'description' argument
```

Then I think it's referring to not being able to plot the dygraphs in Jupyter. I would suggest checking out the "using" section on the [documentation for R dygraphs](https://rstudio.github.io/dygraphs/index.html). Although it doesn't strictly mention using dygraphs in Jupyter notebooks, it gives pointers for using them in R Console, R Markdown, and R Shiny. Lately I've been using them in an R shiny application and they've worked flawlessly, just as long as you set them up correctly. Also, just use:

```
install.packages('dygraphs')
```

in Jupyter notebooks to ensure successful installation and use. I've noticed that there are inconsistencies when running conda install commands (i.e. whether or not the package will end up working in Jupyter notebooks, RStudio, or both).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not in the install `dygraphs`, but it depends on jupyter notebook, this one can't appear dynamic graphic such as in RMarkdown.